# Como tornar um FloatingActionButton quadrado ou retangular?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho 2 *Floating Action Buttons* na tela. Como posso torná-los retangulares?

Comment: Pelo que saiba Fab são sempre redondos, eu já utilizei um cardview com um button pra simular o efeito.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma solução para deixar ele quadrado seria é usar `borderWidth` inserindo `0dp` para o seu `FloatingActionButton`. Então resultaria nisso:

#### Código

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

FloatingActionButton:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab_1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"/>
```

Veja o [código no Gist](https://gist.github.com/cleidimarviana/2df3bbda7fccc46fff368388fd8dbd01).

#### Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]